# Properties of subset of set of bijections having a basic property

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics

Let $G(S)$ is the set of all bijections of a set $G$ Let $s$ be a fixed element of $G$. I want to show that the subset $H$ of $G(S)$ satisfies identity function, closure under composition of functions and existence of inverse function, where $H$ is defined as all functions  that fix $s$, i.e, all $f$ such that $f(s) = s$

Ok. So I define $H:= {x|f(s)=s}$. Obviously by its very definition, this set satisfies the identity function. But how do I show this?
To show closure under composition, I assume there is another function, say $k(s) \in H$. Then $f(k(s))=f(s)=s$. Is this valid?
How about showing that $H$ is closed under inverses?
So I want to show that if $f$ is in $H$, so is $f$ inverse.
I don't really know how to show this. Since f fixes every element, $f$ inverse is equal to f and since $f$ is in the subset, then so is $f$ inverse. Does this work?

Comment: Huh? Shouldn't you consider the set of all functions $f$ that satisfy $f(s)=s$? If $h$ is the identity function, does it satisfy $h(s)=s$? (Hint: it is the identity function, what does that mean)? Etc.?

Comment: Hint: G(S) is a group (why?). You can use this fact to easily show the required properties of the subset H you have defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a short preliminary, let us show that $G(S)$ is a group under composition:
Composition of two bijections $f,g:S\rightarrow S$ is again a bijection on $S$ since both maps are injective and surjective, hence the composite also has those properties (this is easy to show, I will leave that to you; assume both maps have property, show that the composite also does). Function composition is associative, since

$((f\circ g)\circ h)(x)=(f\circ g)(h(x))=f(g(h(x)))=f((g\circ h)(x))=(f\circ (g\circ h))(x)$

There is an identity in $G(S)$, namely the function $\operatorname{id}_S:S\rightarrow S:s\mapsto s$. (You should prove that $\forall f\in G(S)$, $\operatorname{id}_S\circ f=f\circ\operatorname{id}_S=f$; just take any $s\in S$ and shove it through both of the composites). Lastly, for inverses, note that a function $f$ has an *inverse that is a function* (aka  *is an invertible function*) if and only if $f$ is a bijection (This is also straightforward to prove, namely you need to show that the inverse *relation* $f^{-1}$ satisfies the defining properties of a function if and only if it is a bijection; this amounts to showing that injectivity of $f$ implies that elements have unique pre-images under $f$, and surjectivity of $f$ implies that every element of $S$ has a pre-image under $f$).

Having shown all of that, you have proven that $G(S)$ is a group, and also done the hard part. To get the result you need, all you need to do is prove that $H$ is a subgroup of $G(S)$. An easy way to do this is the One Step subgroup test:

A subset $H$ of a group $G(S)$ is a subgroup of that group if $\forall a,b\in G(S)$ you have that $a\circ b^{-1}\in H$.

Note that, in the present case, we have that if $a,b\in H$, then their composite also fixes $s$ and hence is in $H$, moreover, since $b$ fixes $s$, so to does it's inverse because the pre-image of $s$ under $b$ must be $s$, hence we have shown that $b^{-1}\in H$. Thus once again, we have the composite, this time $a\circ b^{-1}$, which fixes $s$ and thus is in $H$. Therefore, by the One Step Subgroup Test, we conclude that $H$ is a (sub)group (and hence, in particular, with respect to the operation of function composition, is associative, has an identity, and has inverses).